# python - Replacing value in a numpy array's column given index from a vector with the same rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, indexing

```
A = np.zeros(shape = (3,4))
A = [[0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0]]

B = np.asarray[[2],[0],[3]]
```

Without a for loop, is there a simple way to change the value of the a components in A (to 1 for example), given the index in B

Such that:

```
A = [[0 0 1 0]
     [1 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 1]]
```

I have been able to get this output with a for loop but would prefer it if it didn't for scalability in higher dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at numpy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

You can do

```
A[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 3]] = 1
```

We are indexing to fetch 3 locations and set a value, thus the lists used to index are each len 3. And `A` has 2 dims, so we use two lists (you can also use only one list if you want to fetch full rows).

It also works with arrays

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), [2, 0, 3]] = 1
```